# Why can't I see my TableViewRowActions buttons (in swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I would like to implements the swipe movement on all my cells in my tableview.
After reading 4 different tutorials, I don't understand why my action buttons don't appear : I can do the "swipe", I can see a blank space where the buttons supposed to be. Even my handlers are not called on click...

```
class RestaurantsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mTableView: UITableView!

private var restosList = [Restaurant]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["service" : "restaurants"])
        .responseArray { (response: [Restaurant]?, error: NSError?) in
            if let response = response {
                for oneResto in response {
                    self.restosList.append(oneResto)
                }
            }
            self.mTableView.reloadData()
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.mTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.restosList[indexPath.row].nom

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.restosList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var alert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = self.restosList[indexPath.row].description
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alert.show()

    self.mTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let deleteClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        println("Delete closure called")
    }

    let moreClosure = { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        println("More closure called")
    }

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: deleteClosure)
    let moreAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "More", handler: moreClosure)

    return [deleteAction, moreAction]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Intentionally blank. Required to use UITableViewRowActions
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to post the code about all the tableviewController,because the code you post is ok

Comment: Ok, I just put the entire class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the canEditRowAtIndexPath method to your view controller and return true.

I usually put my handler code in as a closure right into the parameter but I don't think that should make a difference.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var myItems = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"]

@IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myItems.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = myItems[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Okie dokie
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {


    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit", handler: {

        Void in

        println("edit swipe")

    })

    let superAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Super", handler: {

        Void in

        println("super swipe")

    })

    return [editAction, superAction]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: I will add code to my answer in a few minutes that you can verify against.

Comment: I have the same, but still not working. Maybe it's because I use a custom cell ?

Comment: It shouldn't be, I use it with custom cells as well.

Comment: Did you assign the table view delegate to self?

Comment: Yes. There isn't a method to implement in the custom cell ?

Comment: Nope, this is a different part of the tableView. Though you can try to change the way you init your cell - I'm not sure why you're registering the class for what looks like a regular cell, also you're creating the cell from the tableView variable in your class but didn't register that as a delegate, try to remove self.mTableView.registerClass in viewDidLoad and then create the cell like var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeReusableCellwithIdentifier, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... If I remove `self.mTableView.registerClass(...` with the cell identifier, the compiler will not know `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell")` ..?

Comment: Do you have a prototype cell on storyboard? I am curious why you're registering the cell like this. My point is to make the table as simple as possible and to use the tableView given to you cellForRowAtIndexPath method and not mTableView).

Comment: Ooh, ok I didn't notice that you write tableView and note mTableView in your last response ! That works with the tableView parameter. Thanks you, but I don't understand why when I copied/pasted your code it didn't work...

Comment: I am not sure why that would not work but I am very happy that it is working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Try reload the table view data with this code.

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```